# Google Analytics - Adjusted Bounce Rates don't have many data

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics, joomla

I am trying to install google Analytics and google Tag manager on my site (CMS Joomla). I installed the gogole analytics code in the header :

```
<header>   
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
    <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXX');</script>
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->

    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->

    <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('js', new Date());
      gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXX-X');

    setTimeout("ga('send','event','adjusted bounce rate','More than 30 seconds')",30000); // -- Adjusted Bounce Rate
    </script>
</header>
```

But on my GA information panel I am not receiving any data regarding the bounce rate.
On Tag manager I configured as follows in trigger group on scroll and visit time : [Google Tag - bounce rate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5bYl.png)

However, my rate is no longer up to date:
[Google Analytics taux de rebond bas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGmpo.png)

The site is as follows: [Site joomla](https://sekoya.ch)

Will you have an idea of why my rate is not representative of my visits to the site please?

Thank's in advance for you're help ! :)

Answer (score 0):

I've just visited your site and used [google tag assistant](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-by-google/kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk?hl=en) to see what is happening. Just on the first page load I got three page view tags and 2 events fired - that means visitors are no longer bouncing because Google Analytics thinks they've visited 3 pages.

From [google support pages](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009409?hl=en): "A bounce is a single-page session on your site. In Analytics, a bounce is calculated specifically as a session that triggers only a single request to the Analytics server..."

So you will need to fix your GA tag triggers. Screenshot from my visit:

[image]